# Gatsby site hosted on Microsoft IIS server giving 404 errors for static assets and other files

Tags: reactjs, iis, gatsby

I am trying to host a Gatsby site on a remote Microsoft IIS server. I have copied the contents of the `public` folder of Gatsby to the folder of the IIS server. The site works but all my images in the static folder, web manifest file and some other files being referenced are not found. I have a lot of 404 errors in my console. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be a permission issue, can you provide detailed information about the 404 error?

Comment: @samwu It just says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`. Trying to open the exact url returns a 404 Not Found Server error

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this error message, I suggest you use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Thanks @samwu. I was finally able to get to the root of the error. It was the .webmanifest and .webp files that were causing the 404 errors. I had to add a MIME type in the web.config to support them and it worked

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you share solution as answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it by add the MIME types of .webmanifest and .webp to the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="static">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <remove name="cache-control" />
                    <add name="cache-control" value="public, max-age=31536000, immutable" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="page-data">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <remove name="cache-control" />
                    <add name="cache-control" value="public, max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
              <rule name="AdjustCacheForDontCacheFiles" preCondition="IsDontCacheFile" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache-Control" pattern=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="public, max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
              </rule>
              <rule name="AdjustCacheForCachePermanentlyFiles" preCondition="IsCachePermanentlyFile" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache-Control" pattern=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="public, max-age=31536000, immutable" />
              </rule>
              <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsDontCacheFile">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*\.html)|(sw\.js)|(app\-data\.json)|(page\-data\.json)" />
                </preCondition>
                <preCondition name="IsCachePermanentlyFile">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="((.*\.js)|(.*\.css))$" />
                </preCondition>
              </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)?

It’s required to define the `outboundRules` in the `web.config`, that should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="static">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <remove name="cache-control" />
                    <add name="cache-control" value="public, max-age=31536000, immutable" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="page-data">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <remove name="cache-control" />
                    <add name="cache-control" value="public, max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
              <rule name="AdjustCacheForDontCacheFiles" preCondition="IsDontCacheFile" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache-Control" pattern=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="public, max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
              </rule>
              <rule name="AdjustCacheForCachePermanentlyFiles" preCondition="IsCachePermanentlyFile" stopProcessing="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache-Control" pattern=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="public, max-age=31536000, immutable" />
              </rule>
              <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsDontCacheFile">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*\.html)|(sw\.js)|(app\-data\.json)|(page\-data\.json)" />
                </preCondition>
                <preCondition name="IsCachePermanentlyFile">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="((.*\.js)|(.*\.css))$" />
                </preCondition>
              </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Check Deploying to [Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-to-iis/) for further details.

To me it looks like redirection issues that results in 404 error.

Comment: Thank you. The main cause of the 404 error was as a result of the unsupported file types of .webp for images and .webmanfest. I added the mimeMap both of them into the web.config file and it worked.